# JSDoc - JS overload functions/methods

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've been trying to document an overload function in JS using JSDoc:

There's 2 use cases:

```js
assignSlave(ticket, userid);
assignSlave(ticket, firstname, lastname);
```

I'd like to have it look like this in VSCode:

- Case 1

  [image: Case 1]
- Case 2

  [image: Case 2]

And so on...

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523358/document-overloaded-function-in-jsdoc) but it didn't work for me:

```js
/**
 * Test
 *
 * @function assignSlave
 * @param {String} ticket
 * @param {String} userid
 *//**
 * Test2
 *
 * @function assignSlave
 * @param {String} ticket
 * @param {String} firstname
 * @param {String} lastname
 */
function assignSlave(a, b, c){}
assignSlave()
```

I get this:

[image: this]

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

ETA: I tried [this article](https://austingil.com/typescript-function-overloads-with-jsdoc/) but am not sure how it works in my case.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://austingil.com/typescript-function-overloads-with-jsdoc/

Comment: @Cerbrus From [this article](https://austingil.com/typescript-function-overloads-with-jsdoc/), `@type` and `@template` didn't worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like the following snippet. Change from `function` to an `arrow function` and set its type accordingly. The last thing is to assign a default value to trailing arguments so the overload types are compatible with each other.

```js
/**
 * @type  {{
 *   (ticket: string, userid: string): void;
 *   (ticket: string, firstname: string, lastname: string): void;
 * }}
 */
 const assignSlave = (a, b, c = '') => {}
 assignSlave('ticket', 'userid')
 assignSlave('ticket', 'firstname', 'lastname')
```

This way the function is recognized with 2 overloads:

Overload 1

[image: Overload 1]

Overload 2

[image: Overload 2]

Comment: Thank you so much !! It works exactly like I wanted to !

Comment: I don't know how to do, I don't see the chcek button ;_; Never mind, I'm dumb

Comment: While this works, you should note that you unfortunately lose typing on the anonymous inner function. In the above example, the types of `a`, `b`, and `c` are all `any`. Similarly that function can return whatever it likes and is not constricted to `void`.

Answer (score 6):

In TypeScript 5, you can use the new `@overload` tag:

```js
/**
 * @overload
 * @param {string} ticket
 * @param {string} userId
 *//**
 * @overload
 * @param {string} ticket
 * @param {string} firstname
 * @param {string} lastname
 *//**
 * @param {string} a
 * @param {string} b
 * @param {string} c
 */
function assignSlave(a, b, c) {}
```

For reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#overload-support-in-jsdoc

Comment: this saved me a bunch of time; thanks