# Documentation of function overloading for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a function in Google Apps Script,
In the function, an option to insert one argument, or three arguments is defined.
I've added documentation for script users as written [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73371142/23128179)

This is my code:

```
/**
  * @type {{
  * (Date: 'Hebrew date'): Date;
  * (Day: 'A day in the Hebrew month', Month: 'Hebrew month', Year: 'Hebrew year'): Date;
  * }};
  */
const GDate = (D, M = '', Y = '') => {
// If only one parameter is entered, get the first word for a day, the last word for a year, and the rest of the words for a month (sometimes the Hebrew month name consists of two words).
if (!M) H = D.split(' '), D = H.shift(), Y = H.pop(), M = H.join(' ');

D = letterToNum(D);
M = monthMap[findClosest(M, monthMap)];
Y = letterToNum(Y, 1);

var G = HG(Y);

var days = G.daysmonth.slice(0, G.monthsYear.indexOf(M)).reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);
G.Date.setDate(G.Date.getDate() + days + D);
return G.Date;
}
```

[Documentation for entering a full Hebrew date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyF5f.png)

[Documentation for entering a Hebrew date in day, month, year format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvV2J.png)

Can I add similar documentation for a Google Sheets user
To show it one option for entering one argument,
And a second option for introducing the three arguments?

And how can I make Google Sheets not show the script documentation?

```
/**
  * This function calculates the corresponding Gregorian date from a given Hebrew date.
  * The function can accept the Hebrew date as a single string or as separate strings for day, month and year.
  *
  * @type {{
  * (Date: 'Hebrew date'): Date;
  * (Day: 'A day in the Hebrew month', Month: 'Hebrew month', Year: 'Hebrew year'): Date;
  * }};
  *
  * @param {string} D - full Hebrew date or day of the Hebrew month.
  * @param {string} M - Hebrew month.
  * @param {string} Y - Hebrew year.
  * @return {Date} the corresponding Gregorian date.
  * @customfunction
  */
```

The documentation in Google Sheets also shows the word @type...

And I also cannot write a parameter for a full Hebrew date because it is not recognized in the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response,
Through your response I came to this answer:
[JSDoc - JS overload functions/methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73371142/23128179)
The problem is that I don't know how to write arguments. Length